# Build tree from Array javascript with parent id inside brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, tree

Now before you mark this question as duplicate, hear me out.

i have a json response in reactjs that goes like

```
organisationUnits: [
  {
     name: "0.Mzondo",
     id: "nW4j6JDVFGn",
     parent: {
       id: "Ppx2evDIOFG"
     }
 },
 {
   name: "1 Chipho",
   id: "eE4p4gXpR4p",
   parent: {
     id: "JKNTgsOVMOo"
   }
 }, {}, {}, ....
  
}]
```

now I have searched the net for a list-to-tree solution i've a lot of code from people but it doesn't seem to work.
Ive also tried https://github.com/yi-ge/js-tree-list and https://www.npmjs.com/package/list-to-tree and also https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-to-tree

but nothing works, i assume its because my parent id is trapped in the parenthesis. So nothing online works. If anyone has a solution to this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why you don't change parent.id to parent before using those libs

Comment: Have you considered just writing a function for this yourself? I don't imagine it would take that much effort.

Comment: @evgenifotia I'm truly sorry for being dumb.... such a simple idea and you've saved me time.... thank you sooo much

Answer (score 0):

Okay for all those that may get stuck in the future, here's how i solved the issue.

surprisingly I'm not very bright, so wrong career choice.... here goes

```
var arrayToTree = require('array-to-tree');

var array = [
  {
     name: "0.Mzondo",
     id: "nW4j6JDVFGn",
     parent: {
       id: "Ppx2evDIOFG"
     }
 },
 {
   name: "1 Chipho",
   id: "eE4p4gXpR4p",
   parent: {
     id: "JKNTgsOVMOo"
   }
 }, {}, {}, ....
  
} 

array.map((item) => {
                    //

                    if(item.parent != null){
                        //console.log(item.parent.id)
                        item.parent = item.parent.id
                    } else {
                        item.parent = undefined
                    }
                });

                var tree = arrayToTree(array, {
                    parentProperty: 'parent',
                    customID: 'id'
                });

                console.log( tree );

                this.setState({
                    orgUnits : tree
                });
```

done.
Thank you so much to all those that helped. like really